# If I vacuum seal a food product like beef stew then boil it in the bag, would it keep un-refrigerated?

Tags: food-safety

I'm wondering if after vacuum sealing something then boiling it, if that would act as sterilization allowing the product to remain safe without being refrigerated.

Answer (score 5):

No, definitely not. It's not possible to safely preserve meat by boiling alone.

The only way to do this kind of thing at home is with a pressure canner, which lets you reach higher temperatures to properly kill everything dangerous.

See for example the [NCHFP advice on canning meats](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can5_meat.html).