# After few day of plastick bag packing of Tomato sauce increase the size of it and produce gas in plastic bag

Tags: sauce, food-preservation, tomatoes, food-processing

I am one small manufacturer of tomato sauce and dates sauce . And my question is regarding preservative i.e we make tomato sauce and paking it in plastic bag after few day this paket size increasing and produce gas in plastic bag ,so I want to know about proper method of manufacturing . Our preservatives are sodium benzoate, acitic acid and suger.

Comment: You need to use a method approved by your country's food safety regulations.

Comment: And you do realize that a bloated package means that you have a spoiled product that must be discarded, right?

Comment: Are you refrigerating the bags of sauce? Regardless of what preservatives you use, I don't see how your bagged product could possibly be shelf stable.

Comment: @csk : "tomato sauce" means different things by country.  I assume by the name he's Indian, which would be British English, and so what the Americans call Ketchup.  So there'd also be vinegar, salt, and reduced moisture.

Comment: @Joe That's fair. Still, I'm concerned by the idea of home-packaging a sauce in plastic bags. And if it's not home-packaged, but rather packaged using similar equipment to what ketchup factories use, I think that would be off topic for this site.

Comment: @csk  They said "small manufacturer".  That might not be home-packaging, as we occassionally get a few people asking questions on here that aren't really home cooking.  (there was someone asking about bulk purchasing of popcorn for import to their country just a few days ago)

Comment: relevant:  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/69424/can-canning-be-achieved-with-vacuum-sealed-bags